How to make the curved part of this traffic light?

How do I make the curve parts of this traffic light in blender?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Create a cylinder (Cap Fill Type > Nothing):

In Edit mode, rotate 90° on X, delete the bottom half:

Move the bottom vertices backwards:

Select all and AltE > Extrude Faces Along Normals to give thickness:


Add a circle mesh
TAB to go into Edit mode
Delete enough vertices such that the edges that are left resembles the required shape.
Select the remaining vertices and press E to extrude along the Y-axis to get the thickness of the the shape. Press S to scale, to fan the upper vertices outward.
Select all vertices and extrude along the Z-axis.
Alternatively, just create a plane scale it along the X-axis to make it rectangular. Apply a bend modifier to shape it and a solidify modifier to give it thickness.
